# What will happen if I delete my own post with score?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This is not related to [Deleting my own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96670/deleting-my-own-question)

If I have a question which has a score, let's say 5, and no-one has answered the question.

- What will happen if I delete that question?
- Will I lose the points and badges gained through particular question?

Comment: Why delete a question? You can edit it to make it better or set bounty to attract more attention..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will lose the reputation (though you may need to run a recalculation in order to see this).

Badges will not be lost, though if it is a badge that can be awarded multiple times you might not get awarded the next one that applies to the same conditions it was granted for on the deleted post.

Comment: Badge will stay, but as far as I know, it will cause the next badge not to be granted. For example deleting question with 10 upvotes or more will cause the next question with 10+ to not grant the "Nice Question" badge as you have one "extra".